# How to trace out values from three different tables SQL JOIN?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have 3 tables like below

```
table_1

securityno name    price
1           a11    12.12
2           z11    44.4

table_2

name      identifier Mainprice
a11_bond  NO34         11
z22_bond  NO98         22

table_3
securityno name    identifier 
1           a11    NO34         
2           z11    NO98
```

I want to check whether `table_1` is having correct price or not as per `table_2`. I just want to display output `table_1` data and `Mainprice` column from `table_2`.

```
securityno name    price Mainprice
1           a11    12.12 11
2           z11    44.4  22
```

I was trying like

> select * from table_1 left join table_2 on what about table_3?

failed to use 3 tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT  
    t1.*,  
    t2.Mainprice  
FROM table_1 AS t1  
LEFT JOIN table_3 AS t3  
   ON t1.securityno = t3.securityno AND t1.name = t3.name  
INNER JOIN table_2 AS t2  
   ON t2.identifier = t3.identifier
```

Comment: All values from FROM ` table_1` so need to use `LEFT JOIN` 
And if any ` t2.identifier = t3.identifier` `identifier` not matching that company names from `table_1` also need to display ??

Comment: Try the changed code and let me know if it works. It would be helpful if you can add sample data for the cases you mentioned to the question

Answer (score 2):

Simple use `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT T1.*,
       T2.mainprice
FROM TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN Table3 T3 ON T3.securityno = T1.securityno
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T2.identifier = T3.identifier
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/db2f0/6)

Comment: All values from FROM ` table_1` so need to use `LEFT JOIN` 
And if any ` t2.identifier = t3.identifier` `identifier` not matching that company names from `table_1` also need to display ??